# Android tilemap error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a tilemap but when I run my app, there is nothing on the screen :c

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout tileMap;
int width, height = 1;

int[][] map = {
        {0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tileMap = new LinearLayout(this);
    generate(tileMap, this);
    setContentView(tileMap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

void generate(LinearLayout tileMap, Context context) {

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0 ; x < width; x++) {
            ImageView tile = new ImageView(context);
            tile.setImageResource(R.drawable.wall);
            tileMap.addView(tile);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code ?
I'm pretty sure that the problem's inside the generate function... I've already tried to do an ImageView array but it didn't work either !
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int width, height = 1;
```

You think that width has been initialized to 1, but not. In fact, it has not been initialized and the default value for an `int` is 0.

Hence `for(int x = 0 ; x < width; x++) {` will never run since `x < width` is never evaluated to `true`.

So initialize both:

```
int width = 1;
int height = 1;
```